# Azure virtual server RDP re enable after shutdown

Tags: azure, firewall, rdp, endpoints

I've stopped my virtual server and then started it.
after restart i lost the ability to access remotly to my server (rdp).
i have the needed end point for remote access but is still not working.
i have tried to :
1) delete end point and re-create it.
2) scale up my server forward and backward.

still it look like it can be two things:
1) rdp service after server start is down
2) no firewall rule is created.

notify that after server was started it's IP Address was changed!!!

Thanks

Comment: unfortunatly, I deleted the server and recreated it. didnt get any reasonable answer from anyone. buy the way even microsoft's support told to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use server name not IP, as IP may change.
2. Make sure that you use external port specified in the endpoint.
3. Make sure that your private port is set to 3389.
4. Make sure TCP is selected as the protocol.

Comment: sorry, Did all the above!

Comment: And what is precisely happening when connecting?

Comment: [Window Title]
Remote Desktop Connection

[Content]
Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
2) The remote computer is turned off
3) The remote computer is not available on the network

Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.

[OK] [Help]

Comment: This is how my end point look for rdp
Remote Desktop TCP 58660 3389

Comment: And server name? I can't RDP now but will be able to help in 8h. Unless someone else can try to RDP

Comment: is there a way like a using a fire wall command line with my server cred to add a rule?

Comment: Adding endpoint in management portal creates a firewall rule. I said that if you provide a server name I could test if I can open an RDP connection.

Comment: can we go elsewhere to chat ,or use team viewer ?

Comment: I will be available to help at 22:00GMT. Drop me an email at   jkonecki at gmail.